# Type of generics method return value

Tags: c#, generics

It seems to me like I should be able to do this? But I can't.

```
public Dictionary<Type, List<ParserRuleContext>> Contexts { get; private set; }

public IEnumerable<T> GetAllContextsOfType<T>() where T:ParserRuleContext
{
    return (List<T>)Contexts[typeof(T)];
}
```

This produces the error:

```
Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ParserRuleContext>' 
to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>'
```

Given that List is constrained to be List<ParserRuleContext> by the where clause, I don't understand this?

Comment: Have you tried change to return List<T>?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because *you* know that, for a particular `Type`, you're only going to store objects of *that* specific type in the `List<ParserRuleContext>` stored here<sup>1</sup>:

```
public Dictionary<Type, List<ParserRuleContext>> Contexts
```

There's not enough information for the type system to also know that fact. So far as it's concerned, each of those lists could contain all kinds of objects, all deriving from `ParserRuleContext`. Such a list obviously couldn't be directly cast to any more specific type of list.

And generic types don't (generally) mirror any inheritence structure that their type parameters do. So it's not like you might have stored a `List<TypeDerivedFromParserRuleContext>` in this dictionary - because `List<TypeDerivedFromParserRuleContext>` doesn't inherit from `List<ParserRuleContext>`.

---

<sup>1</sup>At least, I assume that that's the assumption by which you believe that the rest of this code "made sense"

Answer (score 6):

I believe that should be the fact that the instance of the list being with a different tipage the list in the dictionary, if you make a cast with linq is to solve

```
return Contexts[typeof(T)].Cast<T>();
```

or

```
return Contexts[typeof(T)].ToList<T>();
```

Comment: This fixes the problem thanks (not sure why I didn't think of this). I am still not sure why it's needed though.

Comment: Though, instead of casting, it creates completely new object, which might hide the actual issue.

Comment: As already said I believe that should be the instance of the list, so that if you give a typeof the two different typing will bring you think so:: System.Collections.Generic.List [T genérico ...] e System.Collections. Generic.List [ParserRuleContex]